# Alsamixer mutes Headphone gain everytime I reboot

Tags: sound, alsa, headphones

Everytime Ubuntu startups, alsamixer looks like this: [Image](https://imgur.com/a/ZCBCsZg)

Nevertheless, the volume isn't zero, it's very very low, but not zero (because of the second knob, I think).

The "Headphones" are really the laptop speakers (I had some problems with the audio card because it's a chinese laptop).

This is annoying cause I have to unmute and increase the volume everytime I start my PC.

EDIT: This DOESN'T happen when I plug in my headphones. Also, it's important to mention that when Ubuntu startups, the mentioned knob is the only one that changes/mutes, there is no problem with the rest of the controls.